# Creating NPM Package custom events

Tags: javascript, typescript, events, npm, dom-events

I'm building a simple npm package using signalr.
The flow is this:

- User installs install my package
- Package opens a connection using signalr
- At some point, server invoke a function and sends data to it.
- User should be able to “listen” and wait for this data

I expect the user to do something like:

```
myPackage.on(“dataInTheHouse”, (data) => {
const myData = data;
});
```

More or less...

I tried using npm package called “event-emitter”, but couldn’t understand how to make dynamic function for all events, and honestly got a bit confused.

What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer update:

I managed to do it the following way.
(I wrote my package using typescript by the way):

You need to declare a new variable.
For example:

```
events = new EventEmitter();
```

And then,
Inside the function the server invokes, I wrote the following:

```
this.events.emit(“dataInTheHouse”, “This is the data we got!”);
```

And the consumer of my package can just use:

```
this.myPackage.events.on(“dataInTheHouse”, (data) => console.log(data));
```

Easy as that.

For further reading, I found this solution here: https://css-tricks.com/understanding-event-emitters/

Comment: because you are writing a package, I would advise you to expose a more "strict" api. so instead of `events.on(“dataInTheHouse”...)` you could do `events.onDataInTheHouse` and you can have specific parameters to specific events.